# Enter an URL and store with shared preference Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, store

I want the user to enter its URL in my SettingsActivity and that variable is saved for reuse in another Activity (eg Main) and display it in a webview (by adding, for example: http: / / myURL / example1), I know I need to use the shared preference, but I do not know how, can you give me a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to store:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyAppSharedPrefs";

             SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
             editor.putString("UsersUrl", URL HERE);
             editor.commit();
```

Then to get URL:

```
 public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyAppSharedPrefs";

 SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
 String setting = settings.getString("UsersUrl", def);
```

Note: You can chance MyAappSharedPrefs to whatever you want, it's just to identify which shared preferences file you are saving to.
You can also chance UsersUrl, it's just a variable name. 
Say if you set it as: MyUrl, you must also write MyUrl when retrieving setting.

Answer (score 0):

To set:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor sh_ed = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 sh_ed.putString("URL","http://myURL/example1");
 editor.apply();
```

To get:

```
SharedPreferences sh_pr = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String myUrl = sh_pr.getString("URL", null);
```